# Greatest term of the series $a_n ={(2n+1)}^{\frac 1{\sqrt {2n+1}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, maxima-minima

A series is defined such that
 $$a_n = {(2n+1)}^{\frac 1{\sqrt {2n+1}}}, n \in \mathbb Z^+$$

The greatest term of this series is to be found.

I considered defining a function, $f(x) ={(2x+1)}^{\frac 1{\sqrt {2x+1}}}$, taking its derivative and then equating it to zero.

By taking logarithm on both sides of the equation, differentiating and rearranging, I found 
$$ \frac d{dx} f(x) = \frac {\ln (2x+1)(2-\ln(2x+1))}{(2x+1)^2}$$

Equating this to zero and solving for $x$, I found $$x= \frac{e^2-1}2$$
$$\implies 2x+1 \approx 7.4$$ The options for the greatest term were

A)$3^{\frac 1{\sqrt 3}}$

B)$5^{\frac 1{\sqrt 5}}$

C)$7^{\frac 1{\sqrt 7}}$

D)Series is not bounded.

I believe (C) is the correct answer as it was closest to ${7.4}^{\frac 1 {\sqrt {7.4}}}$ .
Is this the correct answer?

Is there any alternate approach?

Comment: Yes, you are right. (C) is the answer.

Comment: An alternate approach is to compute the maximum of those three numbers, knowing that D) is excluded because $a_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Since using derivatives you can see that $x^{2/x}$ is increasing in $[1,e]$, and $\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5} , \sqrt{7} \in [1,e]$ you are done.